# bootstrap 4 on rails 5 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue getting bootstrap to load in rails 5.  I made the mistake of using a product called rapid rails themes (dresssed ives), which is a total piece of garbage, and made a mess of my application.  I've removed this theme and am now having an issue with getting bootstrap to load.  Any advice would be greatly helpful.

I noticed I'm unable to get font-awesome to work as well.  Seems like an issue with the assets pipeline.

Comment: how you tried to work it out?

Comment: You should consider start using a version control tool. Git maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to do it by installing bootstrap manually and adding the following to my config/application.rb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => "reload" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => "reload" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a gem to install it?
I found this gem that adds it to the project which seems pretty straight forward:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem